# When publishing, 70+ languages are shown as supported but my app only haves two

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

When i publish my app, google developer console shows that 70+ languages are supported on my APK but i only have two, english and spanish (values and values-es folders).

I think this happens since i added google play services dependency to my project.

How can this be solved? Why it's happening this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [resource shrinking](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking) feature of the new build system to restrict which languages are included in your APK. Specifically:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        resConfigs "en", "es"
    }
}
```

Comment: did you mean that gradle/androidstudio can't see that i don't have 70 language folders and i only have two? defaultConfig/resConfigs is the only way to achieve this?

Comment: It's putting you in control. If your user has their device set to, say, Korean, you can decide whether that user gets their Play Services things in their preferred language (may be easier for them) or in your app's default language (consistent look & feel).